# unique key-value pairs in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm pretty new to Spark, so forgive my ignorance :). For the following two key-value pairs:

```
dataset  =   sc.parallelize([
             ("a1", "b1"),
             ("b1", "a1"),
             ])
```

is there an efficient and easy way to extract the unique elements? That is, extract only

```
 ("a1", "b1")
```

for example. 
I guess distinct() might do the job, but since it involves shuffling, it should be pretty costly on performance for big Hadoop files. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an exact result then some variant of:

```py
dataset.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).distinct()
```

is pretty much the only option. Intuitively you cannot say if entry occurs more than once unless you gather all possible duplicates of a given value on a single machine.

Depending on your pipeline you can amortize this cost. For example if you plan to `join` or `groupBy` your data later then you can combine this with duplicates removal.

If you can accept data loss and a cost of starting multiple tasks then you can use bloom filter partition by partition.